# Tkinter Callback error - Can not identify the issue

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm somewhat new to python, 6 months and I'm quite sure that my loop here is the issue but I can't determine how to fix it. I've decided to post here after giving it my best for a number of weeks now. Any feedback or help would be appreciated! This is the exception I get, the button works but after sometime it gives me this error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1541, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "G:\My Drive\Python Project\09122019.py", line 82, in Rocker
        client.run_command('sudo python rocknroll_os.py' + ' ' + ssca + ' ' + pisl  +' '+  awb + ' '+ abcvalue +' '+ abcpivalue +' '+ ca +' '+  f +' '+ awbgbv + ' ' + awbgrv + ' ' + delay)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pssh\clients\native\parallel.py", line 223, in run_command
        greenlet_timeout=greenlet_timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pssh\clients\base_pssh.py", line 96, in run_command
        self.get_output(cmd, output, timeout=greenlet_timeout)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pssh\clients\base_pssh.py", line 141, in get_output
        (channel, host, stdout, stderr, stdin) = cmd.get(timeout=timeout)
      File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 709, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.get
      File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 317, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet._raise_exception
      File "src\gevent\greenlet.py", line 766, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pssh\clients\native\parallel.py", line 237, in _run_command
        raise ex
    SessionError









import sys, os
import paramiko
#from paramiko import SSHClient
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.utils import load_private_key
import subprocess
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from mttkinter import *
from mttkinter import mtTkinter
import tkMessageBox
import subprocess

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('1000x800')
root.title("My Window")
bgroundimage = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file='interface_BG.gif')
background_label = Tkinter.Label(root, image=bgroundimage)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

awbs = StringVar()
awbstate = Checkbutton(root, text="State", variable=awbs, onvalue="auto", offvalue="off")
awbgb = Scale(root, from_=0.0, to=8.0, resolution=0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
awbgr = Scale(root, from_=0.0, to=8.0, resolution=0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
delay_time = Scale(root, from_=0.0, to=5000.0, resolution=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
abc = Scale(root, from_=100, to=1600, resolution=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
abcpi = Scale(root, from_=50, to=800, orient=HORIZONTAL)
c  = StringVar()
cn = Entry(root, textvariable = c)
Dss = Spinbox(root, values=('1, '2', '3', '4'))
awbs = Spinbox(root, values=('auto', 'off'))
piss = Spinbox(root, values=('1, '2', '3', '4'))
cfs = Spinbox(root, values=('1, '2', '3', '4'))
delay_time.set(1960)
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user='pi', password='bs', timeout=None)
listenclient = ParallelSSHClient(listeningpis, user='pi', password='bs', timeout=None)

def Rocker(event=None):
        abcvalue = str(abc.get())
        abcpivalue = str(abcpi.get())
        awbgbv = str(awbgb.get())
        awbgrv = str(awbgr.get())
        delay = str(delay_time.get())
        f = c.get()
        ssca = Dss.get()
        ca = cfs.get()
        pisl = piss.get()
        awb = awbs.get()
        client.run_command('sudo python rocknroll_os.py' + ' ' + ssca + ' ' + pisl  +' '+  awb + ' '+ abcvalue +' '+ abcpivalue +' '+ ca +' '+  f +' '+ awbgbv + ' ' + awbgrv + ' ' + delay)
        print 'made it'




Buttonmain = mtTkinter.Button(root, text="RockNRoll", command = Rocker)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code does not run which suggests that you have not posted the actual problematic code. Also; can't find any loop in your code.

Comment: It likely wouldn't run, my apologies, I'm very new here. The "client" is another Pi running the rocknroll_os.py.. I thought the root.mainloop() was a loop? :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. As we (in case it's not a trivial problem) run your code to generate the problem you seek help about we would like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with. As for the loop; it's the event loop which listens for keyboard, mouse etc. events. It doesn't run any of your code unless you want it to, as far as I know.